# get distinct values of string field using elasticsearch query Client java API

Tags: elasticsearch-5

I'm using elasticsearch 5.4

I need to get distinct values of fields using elasticsearch query

I'm trying this query but is not wokring

```
GET /index/index_type/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "distinct": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "status"
      }
    }
  }
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

solution with client java api elasticsearch 5.4

```
import org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregationBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.terms.Terms;
TransportClient client;
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(indexName).setTypes(typeName)
                .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("distinct_line_status").field("line_status.keyword"))
                .setSize(0).get();
        //AggregationProfileShardResult searchHits = response.getAggregations().getAsMap();
        System.out.println(response);
        Terms genders = response.getAggregations().get("distinct_line_status");

        // For each entry
        for (Terms.Bucket entry : genders.getBuckets()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());      // Term
            System.out.println(entry.getDocCount()); // Doc count
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cardinality to achieve this.

```
GET /index/index_type/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "distinct": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "status"
      }
    }
  }
```